# PowerShell sort by Username and by Date

Tags: powershell, sorting

I am trying to dedup a csv file by username and only keep that last date.

[image]

Running this will dedup the username, but does not give me the latest date of the username.

```
import-csv "C:\temp\4-27-all.csv" | Sort-Object "username" -unique
```

What can I add to to make sure I can sort by unique "Username" and only grab the last "Date (UTC)"

Comment: Please share the CSV as plain text instead of screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet:

```sh
Import-Csv C:\temp\4-27-all.csv | 
  Group-Object username |
   ForEach-Object { 
     ($_.Group | Sort-Object 'Date (UTC)' -Descending)[0]
   }
```